# Do React apps have a standard config file similar to .NET's web.config?

Tags: reactjs

One of the standard conventions in .NET apps is the use of a web.config file to store configurable variables and values. These config values anre accessed throughout the app via a WebConfigurationManager class.

Is there any type of equivalent config file and access class used in React apps? I'm not aware of a standard equivalent off-hand.

Comment: No. Because JS-in-general is a less-walled-in environment (read: wild, wild west) there's no real "standards". There are common solutions (e.g., dotenv, plain old JS or JSON, etc) and specific frameworks may have their own conventions.

Comment: Also because your app is running in your users' browsers you need to think about _when_ the config is provided, I wrote about this [on my blog](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html).

Answer (score -1):

In React apps, there is no standard config file equivalent to the Web.config file in .NET. However, it's common to use environment variables to store configurable variables and values. In a React app, you can access environment variables using the "process.env" object. You can set environment variables locally using a .env file or using your hosting provider's environment variable settings. There are also packages like "dotenv" that can help manage environment variables... greetings

Comment: Your hosting provider's env vars are not available to the client, `process.env` access is literally overwritten at build time.